# How to retrieve parameters from Route to Filter?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, localization

I created a filter allowing me to select specific view depending on the value of the parameter lang in the URL. If lang=fr, view_fr.cshtml will be called.

```
public class LocalizedViewAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string defaultLang = "en";

        var routeData = filterContext.RouteData.Values;

        string lang = (string)routeData["lang"];
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(lang))
        {
            defaultLang = lang;
        }

        var viewResult = filterContext.Result as ViewResultBase;
        if (viewResult != null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(viewResult.ViewName))
            {
                viewResult.ViewName = filterContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
            }

            var v = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(
                filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext,
                viewResult.ViewName + "_" + defaultLang, null
                );
            if (v.View != null)
                viewResult.ViewName += "_" + defaultLang;
        }

        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

And the route for the localization

```
 routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Localization",
       url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
       new { lang = "", controller = "Static", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
 );

 routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Default",
       url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Static", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
 );
```

But the parameter "lang" is always empty. What am I doing wrong ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your localization route does not define an optional `id` parameter and it would therefore only match if all four route parameters are present in the URL. Consequently, you're only hitting the default route, which does not have a `lang` parameter.